# Typeahead.js results disappear on each keystroke

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead, typeahead.js

I am using the remote feature of typeahead and instead of the remote occurring like Google's results (the results stay up as you type), each keystroke causes the results to disappear and then 1/2 sec delay to fetch data, and then reappear.

How can I make this behave more like Google's?  The results are coming from about 10K records, so I can't prefetch the whole thing.  I know the new results will always take some time to fetch, but why do the current results go away while that is happening?

Here is my typeahead code:

```
var compiledAddressTemplate = Hogan.compile('<p class="">{{Address}}</p>');
$(".typeahead[id$='__Address1']").typeahead([
{
    name: 'address1-test',
    valueKey: 'Value',
    remote: CurrentController + '/GetAddressLookahead/%QUERY',
    cache: true,
    template: compiledAddressTemplate.render.bind(compiledAddressTemplate), 
    engine: Hogan,
    minLength: 3,
    limit: 100,
    allowDuplicates: true
}
]);
```

I have played with cache and limit to no avail.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately that's just how typeahead.js currently works. There's an issue opened to change this behavior: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/issues/176